# Byte allocation different for dynamic vs. static char array of same size?

Tags: c++, memory, char

So, I ran this code in my IDE. Can anyone explain the reason why the same amount of memory isn't allocated to both of these arrays when they should be the same size?

```
char* dynamicCharArr = new char[15]; //allocates 8 bytes
cout << sizeof(dynamicCharArr) << endl;

char staticCharArr[15]; //allocates 15 bytes
cout << sizeof(staticCharArr) << endl;
```

Comment: `sizeof(dynamicCharArr)` is `sizeof(char*)`.  Because `dynamicCharArr` is a `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new[]` returns a *pointer* to the memory it allocates.  You are printing the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the allocated memory being pointed at.

There is no way for `sizeof()` to query the size of that allocated memory.  If you pass in the pointer itself, you get the size of the pointer. If you pass in the dereferenced pointer, you get the size of 1 element of the array, not the whole array.  In that latter case, you would have to multiply that size by the element count that you pass to `new[]`.

In both examples, the amount of memory accessible to your code is `sizeof(char) * 15`.  But you simply can't obtain that value from a pointer alone, which is why `sizeof(dynamicCharArr)` doesn't work.  In a fixed array, the size is part of the array's type, which is why `sizeof(staticCharArr)` does work.

However, note that the *physical memory* allocated by `new[]` for a dynamic array will always be *slightly larger* than the memory used by a fixed array of the same element count, because `new[]` allocates additional internal metadata that is used by `delete[]`, and even the memory manager itself. That metadata will include (amongst whatever else the memory manager needs internally, like debug info, block tracking, etc) the number of elements that `new[]` allocated, so `delete[]` knows how many elements to destroy.  But `sizeof()` doesn't know (or care about) that metadata.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(dynamicCharArr)` gets you the size of the *pointer* to the `char` array. Try `sizeof` with a dynamic char array of a different size. It will be the same (on the same system).